# forcing composer to regenerate autoloads when composer.json of a dependency is changed?

Tags: composer-php

My workflow for developing Symfony bundles is the following:

- install Symfony
- create a git repo for the new bundle, put a composer.json file in there
- require the new package in the top-level composer.json, using @dev version
- composer update newpackage => the package is downloaded, using git clone
- work on the git clone inside vendors, committing and pushing from it

This is all fine and dandy, but seems to break in one specific case:
if I alter the 'autoload' tag of the already-installed package, it seems that Composer has a hard time taking it into account:

- I tried 'composer dumpautoload', and it does nothing
- I do not want to remove the composer.lock file, as I do not want other packages to be updated to a newer version, I only want to alter the autoload config of that one package
- I tried removing by hand vendor/composer/installed.json, and what happened is that Composer re-downloaded all the vendors and wiped any data which happened to be in there at that moment

The same problem manifested itself when I did alter the autoload section of the package on a separate clone, pushed the changes to git and ran 'composer update mypackage' - although that might have been related to packagist not having received the ping from github.

I can of course alter by hand the composer.lock and vendor/composer/installed.json files, but that seems too hackish. It also does not gives the guarantee that user downloading the package the 1st time will see it working.

Comment: Running "dumpautoload" where? It should be in the top project directory. Alternatively: `composer update your/bundle` will only update this, nothing else.

Comment: @sven I am running composer in the top-level dir. My point is that when I run composer update my/bundle, it seems that composer does not 'see' that it has to update it (in one sense it is right, as the local copy is already at the latest git commit on master), and that it does not regenerate the autoloads reflecting the changes in my/bundle/composer.json

Comment: I have difficulties following what you are doing. Can you prepare a small example that shows what you are experiencing? What are you altering? Where exactly? What is the output of the commands? What is the exact error message from PHP? "Composer has a hard time..." doesn't describe the problem exactly, it's a paraphrased "it doesn't work, and I won't tell you what went wrong when and why".

Comment: It seems pretty obvious what he wants! He wants to make changes to the composer.json files and regenerate all the autoload files so that all the paths and what knot are pointing to the new places. When you do a composer update it must run something after downloading all the files which regenerates all the autoload stuff, so what is it and how can he run it separately.

Answer (score 14):

Try:

```
./composer.phar dumpautoload -o
```

It reads the `composer.json` files and rewrites all the autoload files which pick up the new paths.

Answer (score 4):

`dumpautoload` uses the package information from `vendor/composer/installed.json` and not the individual `composer.json` files. You need to change the autoload info there, too.

Comment: Thanks for this. Where can find that out?

Answer (score 0):

The file installed.json is only being update when you run a

```
composer update
```

Comment: this might also update the packages, which you wouldn't want